# 'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, netbeans, cucumber

I am on Netbeans 8.0.2. I downloaded Cucumber netbeans plugin from here: https://github.com/QuBiT/cucumber-netbeans-plugin/downloads

I have my feature file inside my project. Now when I try to Right click on my feature file and generate class I get this error:

```
--- START ---

'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
--- END ---
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have **NOT** installed cucumber on your machine but have only installed its NetBeans plugin.

In this case, you should see [Cucumber Installation](http://www.guru99.com/cucumber-installation.html)..

If you have installed cucumber on your machine, then the most probable problem is that the System variable **PATH** of your machine does not contain the `path/to/cucumber`.

Comment: This is Ruby. Please see my tag of Java in the question. For java version there is no cucumber setup. The issue was the cucumber feature plugin which is incompatible with the latest Netbeans release. I went on to use Eclipse because it has a nice plugin which works.