# Unable to run cucumber in jenkins through build step as 'Execute windows batch command'

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, watir

I have automation framework using cucumber, watir and ruby.  I wanted to run cucumber tags through Jenkins using build step as 'Execute windows batch command'.
Below are the steps I have followed,

1. In Jenkins, Created a new job item as 'Freestyle project'
2. In build step, I have selected the step as 'Execute windows batch command'

I have given the path of the project location

```
cd C:\Users\testsample

cucumber -t @testtag -f pretty -f json -o reports/test_result.json
```

Then finally I did build now for the above job

Below is the error console.  Can someone pls help

> **C:\Users\testsample>cucumber -t @testtag -f pretty -f json -o reports/test_result.json 'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Comment: Does it works when you run those commands locally on the system ?
Suspecting that there is an issue with installation.

Comment: when i run locally i am able to run cucumber without any error.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Is your cucumber installed location is added into `PATH` variable? How you are executing it ?possible post the required info.Why i'm asking is, basically Jenkins runs all jobs under `jenkins` user privilege in a system. If jenkins user couldn't get the binary path of cucumer it will fail & it will result the same what you mentioned in the question, like `"cucumber" is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Also check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315181/cucumber-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) as well, it may help.

Comment: Any idea if this is resolved? I am facing the same issue currently. My system runs the cucumber command perfectly but the same throws an error in jenkins, with the slave connected to my system